# Where should I include the instantiation in top module(counter)

Tags: counter, debounce

I am doing a counter module in Basys-2 board.This is my instantiation of the debouncing circuit

```
 debouncing U0(
.clock(clock),
.reset(reset),
.button(button),
.out(out)
 );
```

But I am getting an error in Xilinx 14.7 as

WARNING:Xst:646 - Signal  is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1290 - Hierarchical block  is unconnected in block .
   It will be removed from the design.

If at all I have to include this instantiation in counter module,where should I and why am i getting this error.

```
Counter Circuit
module button_binary(
input clock,
input reset,
input button,
output led,
output led2,
output led3,
output led4,
output led5,
output led6,
output led7,
output led8
);

reg [7:0]count;

  always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)
  begin
 if (reset)
    count <= 0;
else if (button)
    count <= count + 1;
end

assign led = count[0];
assign led2 = count[1];
assign led3 = count[2];
assign led4 = count[3];
assign led5 = count[4];
assign led6 = count[5];
assign led7 = count[6];
assign led8 = count[7];
endmodule
```

//Debouncing Module

```
module debouncing(
input clock,
input reset,
input button,
output reg out
);

localparam N = 19;        //for a 10ms tick
reg [N-1:0]count;
wire tick; 

//the counter that will generate the tick.

always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)
 begin
    if(reset)
        count <= 0;
    else
        count <= count + 1;        
 end

 assign tick = &count;        //AND every bit of count with itself. Tick will only go high when all 19 bits of count are 1, i.e. after 10ms

 // now for the debouncing FSM

 localparam[2:0]                     //defining the various states to be used
            zero = 3'b000, 
            high1 = 3'b001,
            high2 = 3'b010,
            high3 = 3'b011,
            one = 3'b100,
            low1 = 3'b101,
            low2 = 3'b110,
            low3 = 3'b111;

reg [2:0]state_reg;
reg [2:0]state_next;

always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)      
 begin
    if (reset)
        state_reg <= zero;
    else
        state_reg <= state_next;
end


always @ (*)
 begin
    state_next <= state_reg;  // to make the current state the default state
    out <= 1'b0;                    // default output low

    case(state_reg)
        zero:
            if (button)                    //if button is detected go to next state high1
                state_next <= high1;
        high1:
            if (~button)                //while here if button goes back to zero then input is not yet stable and go back to state zero
                state_next <= zero;
            else if (tick)                //but if button remains high even after 10 ms, go to next state high2.
                state_next <= high2;
        high2:
            if (~button)                //while here if button goes back to zero then input is not yet stable and go back to state zero
                state_next <= zero;
            else if (tick)                //else if after 20ms (10ms + 10ms) button is still high go to high3
                state_next <= high3;
        high3:
            if (~button)                //while here if button goes back to zero then input is not yet stable and go back to state zero
                state_next <= zero;
            else if (tick)                //and finally even after 30 ms input stays high then it is stable enough to be considered a valid input, go to state one
                state_next <= one;

        one:                                //debouncing eliminated make output high, now here I'll check for bouncing when button is released
            begin
                out <= 1'b1;
                    if (~button)        //if button appears to be released go to next state low1
                        state_next <=  low1;
            end
        low1:
            if (button)                //while here if button goes back to high then input is not yet stable and go back to state one
                state_next <= one;
            else if (tick)            //else if after 10ms it is still high go to next state low2
                state_next <= low2;
        low2:
            if (button)                //while here if button goes back to high then input is not yet stable and go back to state one
                state_next <= one;
            else if (tick)            //else if after 20ms it is still high go to next state low3
                state_next <= low3;
        low3:
            if (button)                //while here if button goes back to high then input is not yet stable and go back to state one
                state_next <= one;
            else if (tick)            //after 30 ms if button is low it has actually been released and bouncing eliminated, go back to zero state to wait for next input.
                state_next <= zero;
        default state_next <= zero;

    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that there is a signal (a `wire` net) that is only "connected" at one end -- it's meaningless to define a wire with a source but no load, or a load but no source. Usually this is the result of either not explicitly declaring the net.

Assuming you intend your top module to wire the `.out` output port of a `debouncing` instance to the `.button` input port of a `button_binary` module, then your top module will look something like this:

```
// Toplevel module ports connect to external FPGA pins
module top (
    input clock,
    input reset,
    input button,
        output led,
        output led2,
        output led3,
        output led4,
        output led5,
        output led6,
        output led7,
        output led8
);

// Declare the wire net that will connect your modules
wire buttonDebounced; //!< driven by inst_debouncing1

// Instantiate the debouncing module 
debouncing inst_debouncing1(
        .clock(clock), //!< external input pin
        .reset(reset), //!< external input pin
        .button(button), //!< from physical button to be debounced
                .out(buttonDebounced) //!< debounced switch output
    );

// Instantiate the button_binary module
button_binary inst_button_binary1(
        .clock(clock), //!< external input pin
        .reset(reset), //!< external input pin
        .button(buttonDebounced), //!< driven by inst_debouncing1
            .led(led), //!< external output pin
            .led2(led2), //!< external output pin
            .led3(led3), //!< external output pin
            .led4(led4), //!< external output pin
            .led5(led5), //!< external output pin
            .led6(led6), //!< external output pin
            .led7(led7), //!< external output pin
            .led8(led8), //!< external output pin
    );

endmodule
```